# validate array of values from select box using jquery validator

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I want to validate each select box .Number of select box is depend on the value retrieved from the databse.. My code is given below..  But Its not working...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#multipleForm").find("status").each(function () {
            $(this).validate({
                rules: {
                    'status[]': {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="update.php" id="multipleForm">
    <?php $cl=m ysql_query( "select * from demo where id='$cid'"); while($v2=mysql_fetch_array($cl)){ ?>
    <label>
        <?php echo $v2[ 'details'] ; ?>
    </label>
    <textarea name="remarks[]"></textarea>
    <label>Status</label>
    <select name="status[]">
        <option value="">select status</option>
        <option value="NC">yes</option>
        <option value="PC">no</option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
</form>`
```

can any one help me please to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here

`$("#multipleForm").find("status")`

you have used `status` as a tag whereas it is not.

Try this instead -
`select[name=status]`

i.e. `$("#multipleForm").find(" select[name=status]" )`

When using jQuery validator plugin, you can also do one thing i.e. you can validate the form instead of selective elements and just use necessary class names for different elements

e.g. 
`<select class='required'>...</select>`

and

`$("#formid").validate();`

**Update**

Try this -

```
 $("#multipleForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        'status': {
                            required: true
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Note:

Make sure that the validator plugin is being loaded in proper order and `.validate()` is ready to be used.

Comment: Have updated the answer. However, I have a query: are you sure that multiple records with the same name will work for you for elements like `textarea` and `select` i.e. `remarks[]` and `status[]` respectively? I believe, you should have used class name instead.